# In git the Files that I haven't changed are automatically committed

Tags: git, github

First I run `git merge master` for new code in my branch then I run the command `git status` which shows that I have committed many files which I didn't touch.
Not sure if it happened due to using linux ubuntu. How can I solve it I have tried to `git merge --abort` and tried again facing the same issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: _"How can I solve it"_ - do what it tells you to? Fix conflicts, in the three files listed, then commit the result.

Comment: Those are the changes from master being merged into your branch. Those changes in green are not committed, they are staged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a merge process has conflicts, Git asks you to solve them as you can see after `git merge master`.
You can use a mergetool or you can solve them manually inside the code where lines have conflicts.